# left join подсчитать значения

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT p.*
FROM poll p
LEFT JOIN poll_answer a ON p.id_poll = a.id_poll
LEFT JOIN poll_answer_user au ON au.id_poll = p.id_poll
WHERE `archive` = 1
  AND `hide` = 0
  OR `enddate` < CURDATE()
```

Нужно подсчитать кол-во совпадений, при склейки poll_answer_user и добавить новый столбец вывода с кол-во совпадений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите посчитать количество ответивших пользователей для каждого опроса. Буквально так:

`SELECT id_poll, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM poll_answer_user
GROUP BY id_poll`

Чтобы добавить поля из таблицы "опросы", используем это как под-запрос:

`` SELECT p.*, IFNULL(gau.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM poll AS p LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT id_poll, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM poll_answer_user
    GROUP BY id_poll
  ) AS gau USING(id_poll)
WHERE
  p.`archive` = 1 AND
  (p.`hide` = 0 OR p.`enddate` < CURDATE()) ``

Кстати, будте осторожны с сочетанием AND и OR. Если не учитывать приоритет операций, можно получить неожиданный результат. Скобки укажут что именно требуется.